# Changing the Variable of Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is my equation, where $ F(\frac xy)$ is my function: (note that both $x$ and $y$ are variables )
$$ \frac {d^2}{dx^2}F(\frac xy) +2 \frac xy \frac {d}{dy}F(\frac xy) +\frac {x^2}{y^2}  \frac {d^2}{dy^2}F(\frac xy)=0$$

My question is: What is the new form of  this equation when I change $\frac xy$ by $t$ so that my equation  becomes

$$ \frac {d^2}{dt^2}F(t).............=0 $$

or some thing like that.
I need a detailed answer if you can??!!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chain rule one have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left\{F\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} = 
\frac{1}y \frac{d F}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=x/y} =
\frac{1}y F'\left(\frac xy\right),$$

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left\{F\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right\} = 
-\frac{x}{y^2} \frac{d F}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=x/y}=
-\frac{x}{y^2} F'\left(\frac xy\right),$$

$$\frac {d^2}{dx^2}\left\{F\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} = \frac {d}{dx}\left\{ \frac{1}y F'\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} = \frac{1}{y^2}F''\left(\frac xy\right),$$
and
$$\frac {d^2}{dy^2}\left\{F\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} = \frac {d}{dy}\left\{ -\frac{x}{y^2} F'\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} = 
\frac{2x}{y^3} F'\left(\frac xy\right)
+\frac{x^2}{y^4}F''\left(\frac xy\right)$$

You are given that 
$$ \frac {d^2}{dx^2}F\left(\frac xy\right) +2 \frac xy \frac {d}{dy}F\left(\frac xy\right) +\frac {x^2}{y^2}  \frac {d^2}{dy^2}F\left(\frac xy\right)=0$$

Thus you have
$$\frac{1}{y^2}F''\left(\frac xy\right) + 
2 \frac xy \left( -\frac{x}{y^2} F'\left(\frac xy\right)\right) + 
\frac {x^2}{y^2}\left(\frac{2x}{y^3} F'\left(\frac xy\right)
+\frac{x^2}{y^4}F''\left(\frac xy\right)\right)=0
$$
which is something very special.

What you probably trying to say is

$$y^2\left(
\frac {d^2}{dx^2}\left\{F\left(\frac xy\right)\right\} + 
\frac{d^2}{dy^2}\left\{F\left(\frac xy\right) ) \right)\right\} =\\
 F''\left(\frac xy\right)
+\frac{2x}{y} F'\left(\frac xy\right)
+\frac{x^2}{y^2}F''\left(\frac xy\right)\underset{t=x/y}{=}\\
F''\left(t\right)
+2t F'\left(t\right)
+t^2 F''\left(t\right)=0
$$

Comment: notice that I've set $ t= \frac xy $ ,to make my equation simpler.not complicated like this

Comment: In Fact the result is this :$$ \frac {d^2}{dt^2}F(t)+ 2 t \frac {d}{dt}F(t)+ t^2  \frac {d^2}{dt^2}F(t) =0 $$      but i haven't understood from where it comes??

Comment: this would be just a simple substitution to your original equation. see the edit in a while

Comment: thank Michael, your answer seems to be satisfactory;but I get confused when you set your functions $g(t)$, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and i tell you that i just make a simple variable change $t=\frac xy$, that's it.sorry for being so beginner!!

Comment: sorry, but i tell u that i haven't understood your functions (read carefully my last comment)

Comment: I thought the new part clarified things. If not, please ask specific question.

Comment: why you don't use $t= \frac xy$ instead of $g(t)=\frac {x(t)}{y(t)}$ and make your demonstration easy (for me)

Comment: I think I did it already and even got rid of $g(t)$

Comment: you need to understand the difference between $F'(x/y)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\{F(x/y)\}$, the first is the evaluation of the derivative of $F$ at point $x/y$, the second is derivative of $F(g(t))$ which is done using a chain rule.

Comment: why $F'(x/y)=\frac {dF}{dx} (x/y)=\frac {dF}{dy} (x/y)$

Comment: they are not equal

Comment: but that's what can i understand from the 1st and 2nd lines; notice that when you derivate just one time in both $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ line

Comment: see the$ $ edit

Comment: really i didn't get it, i 'll check your answer just because you where patient with me

Comment: i believe you need a math tutor who can sit next to you, then this will be fast